# make money with few downloaded game?

Tags: android, google-play

If i publish an android game that's free but with adds will i make money when nobody (or few people) download the game? What are the paying rates? Is it for example $1/100Downloads? I'm really new in the app business!

For example: i use 'admobs' en i write a converter for binary numbers, i want to publish it on play store but i don't know if someone will download it; Will i still make money with the ads? Or will i lose money? I'm new in the app world so i appreciate all help!

regards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming issues.

Comment: oh sorry i thought that some people had experience with the app business.I'm sorry if i misposted it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If nobody download your app you will make no money. Admobs and others pay you for ad print. No download = no ads print = no money

Comment: and will you lose money when its not downloaded?

Comment: You will not be charged from AdMobs. Admobs will charge you only if you promote your app with their services (if you ask to pay).